# Khan Academy: If Statements 2

Tags: javascript, if-statement, khan-academy

My if statement is not working, like last time but this time the line won't `x = x - 2;` in my if statement (I didn't do the `else if` because I thought it's the problem). Link: https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/probability/5609184564559872. Code:

```
var x = 78;
var y = 18;

// Just in case I test
var saveX = 78;
var saveY = 18;

draw = function() {
    background(150, 255, 250);
    
    strokeWeight(1);
    stroke(0, 0, 0);
    rect(78, 20, 254, 25);
    
    strokeWeight(6);
    stroke(255, 0, 0);
    line(x, y, x, y + 29);
    
    
    if (x > 332) {
        x = x - 2;
    }
    
    if (x < 78) {
        x = x + 2;
    }
    
    x = x + 2;
};
```

Comment: There is no `x = x - 1` in your code! What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: What do you mean your "if statement is not working"? Which of the 2 if statements. I have run the program and it seems to be doing something that makes sense. What is your objective? What does this program have to do?

Comment: @p.matsinopoulos both. I will make a probability program.

Comment: whoops, i meant `x = x - 2;` @phuzi

Comment: Your if statement works. if the x starts or reaches a number > 332 then it is decreased by 2. So, if you set your `var x = 350`, for example, then it will become 348 and then, on line `x = x + 2`, it will become 350 again. Or if you start it to be `var x = 300`, it will be increased by 2 (because of the `x = x + 2`) and when it reaches `334`, it will be decreased by 2 (a.k.a. `332`) and then line `x = x + 2` will make it `334` again, which means it will be staying to `334` forever.

Comment: If you want to see the output, go to the link, https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/probability/5609184564559872

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### it works, and the `x = x+2` makes the value is not changing at all

This is what you want for a ping-pong effect, key is the direction variable.

```js
var x = 78;
var y = 18;

// Just in case I test
var saveX = 78;
var saveY = 18;
var direction = 1;

draw = function() {
    background(150, 255, 250);
    
    strokeWeight(1);
    stroke(0, 0, 0);
    rect(78, 20, 254, 25);
    
    strokeWeight(6);
    stroke(255, 0, 0);
    line(x, y, x, y + 29);
    
    
    if (x > 332) {
        direction = -1;
    }
    
    if (x < 78) {
        direction = 1;
    }
    
    x = x + direction * 2;
};
```

Comment: glad to hear that, don't forget to accept the answer

Comment: @ObooCheng. Interesting. How did you know that he wanted to draw a ping-pong effect? The question is so poorly edited.

Comment: @p.matsinopoulos At the right end he is trying to minus the value `if(x > 332){ x=x-2 }`, so I guess he is trying to do so.